# Pivot by Country Name and Flag in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Algeria '{"validated": "correct"}' 5
Algeria '{"validated": "incorrect"}' 1My data looks like this: 
USA '{"validated": "correct"}' 486
USA '{"validated": "incorrect"}' 21
```

and I am trying to cross tab it like this:

```
Country Correct Incorrect
Algeria 5       1 
USA     486     21
```

Here is my SQL query,

```
select * from crosstab
(
select country,validate_obj,count(validate_obj) as row_count
from (
select adg.article_id, to_timestamp(adg.ts_start),adv.validate_obj, regexp_replace(location_name, '.*,', '') as country
from table1 adg 
inner join table2 ade on adg.article_id = ade.article_id 
inner join table3 adv on adg.article_id = adv.article_id 
where adv.ts_end !=0
) as rollup_table
group by country, validate_obj
order by 1,2
, $$VALUES ('{"validated": "correct"}'::text), ('{"validated": "incorrect"}')$$
) AS ct ("country" text, "Correct" int, "Incorrect" int)
```

I am not able to do it since I do not have permissions to create extensions (tablefunc)

Is there an alternate way?

Can you please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you ave only 2 values, you can make the classical approach to pivot

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (
>   "country" VARCHAR(7),
>   "value" JSON,
>   "count_" INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO mytable
>   ("country", "value", "count_")
> VALUES
>   ('Algeria', '{"validated": "correct"}', '5'),
>   ('Algeria', '{"validated": "incorrect"}', '1'),
>   ('USA', '{"validated": "correct"}', '486'),
>   ('USA', '{"validated": "incorrect"}', '21');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> "country",
> MAX(CASE WHEN "value" ->> 'validated'  = 'correct' THEN count_ ELSe NULL END) AS  correct
> ,
> MAX(CASE WHEN "value" ->> 'validated'  = 'incorrect' THEN count_ ELSe NULL END) AS  incorrect
> FROM
>     mytable
> GROUP BY "country"
> ```
>
> ```
> country | correct | incorrect
> :------ | ------: | --------:
> Algeria |       5 |         1
> USA     |     486 |        21
> ```

## a_horse_with_no_name pointed out, that there is also an alternative

> ```
> SELECT 
> "country",
> max(count_) filter (where "value" ->> 'validated' = 'correct') AS  correct
> ,
> max(count_) filter (where "value" ->> 'validated' = 'incorrect') AS  incorrect
> FROM
>     mytable
> GROUP BY "country"
> ```
>
> ```
> country | correct | incorrect
> :------ | ------: | --------:
> Algeria |       5 |         1
> USA     |     486 |        21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b629b79f126175259938723f923c052e)*

Comment: Alternatively: `max(count_) filter (where "value" ->> 'validated' = 'correct')`